# convert dataframe column of type 'object' into type list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to convert the `object` type column of a `dataframe` into a list of `dicts` as it actually needs to be.

```
print df['A'].dtype
object

print df['A'][:1]
[{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]
```

Is it possible to retrieve `df['A']` as a list of `dicts` as `dicts`? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Comment: Given an example of `df['A']`

Comment: df['A'][:1] isn't iterable as a list and is of type 'str'. I want to change it to a list of dicts.
    for items in df['A'][:1]:
        print type(items)
        print items

    <type 'str'>
    [{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `json`

```
import json

df.A.apply(json.loads)

0    [{u'c': 47, u'at': u'con'}, {u'z': 47, u'at': ...
1    [{u'c': 47, u'at': u'con'}, {u'z': 47, u'at': ...
2    [{u'c': 47, u'at': u'con'}, {u'z': 47, u'at': ...
3    [{u'c': 47, u'at': u'con'}, {u'z': 47, u'at': ...
4    [{u'c': 47, u'at': u'con'}, {u'z': 47, u'at': ...
5    [{u'c': 47, u'at': u'con'}, {u'z': 47, u'at': ...
Name: A, dtype: object
```

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        '[{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]',
        '[{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]',
        '[{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]',
        '[{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]',
        '[{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]',
        '[{"at": "con", "c": 47}, {"at": "cli", "z": 47}, {"at": "cks", "d": 5}]',
    ],
    columns=['A'])
```